# ASP.NET SQL statements execution

Tags: asp.net

Couple of days in a row I am trying to master APS.NET authentication process. I am completely confused.

I've created simple website which using Form authentication. ( This is totally magic )
Authentication works well, but have no clue how it works, probably code and SQL statements already injected somewhere deep in framework. But how do I create a custom control?

Lets say I have two categories of users: Member and Moderator.

I want Moderator able to execute `Insert`, `Update`, and `Delete` SQL staments but Member will be restricted for those operations and able to perform `Select` statement only and only for his records.

Could you guys guide me how can I achieve it using ASP.NET. Thanks!

Comment: if an answer helped you, don't forget to accept it as a basic courtesy to others...

Answer (score 2):

First create Member and Moderator roles: https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx

And then just check in which role does the user belong before executing anything: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z6b5d42.aspx

Comment: pOcHa, thanks for your answer. So in this case all the queries which will be executed outside application will be rejected? Say If someone wants outside of my application execute DELETE query (without form authentication) will it succeed?

Comment: @WildGoat no, this is only protecting your from inside the application (people will have to be in the Moderator role)- if somebody knows your db login, they can do whatever they want outside of it...

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get what do you mean. Could you please articulate it somehow. So if people know my connection string to db they can delete everything from my DB?

Comment: @WildGoat exactly! but you could encrypt the connection string (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/021506-1.aspx), or use a restricted login in the connection string (just selects) - and hard code the privileged login inside the app

Comment: But shouldn't it be already implemented by ASP.NET? it so popular problem I guess it should be somehow covered already. : (

Comment: @WildGoat what should be already implemented by ASP.NET? if someone has access to your connection string (or sql login) then **you** are doing something very, very wrong...

Answer (score 2):

You can create roles for both categories (Member and moderator).

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/roles/creating-and-managing-roles-vb

For custom membership roles, check the below link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27955/Developing-custom-ASP-NET-Membership-and-Role-prov